# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grey_goose

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I know that this error occurs when we have not included JAR file in the classpath, but I have already done that and my JDBC program in the same project runs perfect, but when I am trying to use JDBC with servlet, it gives me this error.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grey_goose

I have tried all the solutions in Stack Overflow, but the problem persists.

I also tried to add

> Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

but it gives me another error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

This is my servlet

```java
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        //final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grey_goose";
        String uname="root";
        String pass="Karmveer@2001";
        String query="SELECT * FROM customer limit 3";

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>"); 
 
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            out.println("<table border=1 width=50% height=50%>");  
            out.println("<tr><th>cust_number</th><th>name_customer</th><th>"); 
            while(rs.next()) {                  
                String n = rs.getString("cust_number");  
                String nm = rs.getString("name_customer");  
    
                out.println("<tr><td>" + n + "</td><td>" + nm + "</td></tr>");   
            }
            out.println("</table>");  
            out.println("</html></body>");  
            
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.akaaliStudios.MainServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MainServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

A separate JDBC program is running fine in the same project that means that JAR files are loaded correctly, but the problem comes when I try to use JDBC with servlets.

1. I have added connector JAR file in lib folder of Tomcat installation folder
2. connector JAR file is added in web deployment assembly in project properties.
3. connector JAR file is added in class path of Java build path in project properties.
4. connector JAR file is added in bootstrap entries of launch configuration Tomcat server.

Comment: Does your project contain a module-info.java? If so, does it include `requires java.sql;`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No my project does not contain module-info.java

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of another situation that would cause a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver`, as that class is part of the JRE. Could you post the full exception stacktrace?